# Select the element in which it belongs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

There are radio buttons in the ".bar"
I show the selected input radio value in "div class='selected-item'".
Name values must all be the same.
The choice in each .bar, should be written on ".selected-item" in itself.
When I select in the first ".bar", the second ".bar" value also changes.
How can i fix it.
The .radio selection should change the value of .selected-item in the .bar it is in.

```js
$('.bar input[name="exa"]').on('change', function() {
 var selectedprice = $('.bar input[name=exa]:checked').val();
 $( ".selected-item b" ).text( selectedprice );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bar">
 <h2>This is first bar. class name "bar"</h2>
 <div class="selected-item">Selected İtem: <b>130</b></div>
 <label>
  <input type="radio" name="exa" value="130" />
  130
 </label>
 <label>
  <input type="radio" name="exa" value="140" />
  140
 </label>
 <label>
  <input type="radio" name="exa" value="150" />
  150
 </label>
 <label>
  <input type="radio" name="exa" value="160" />
  160
 </label>
</div>

<div class="bar">
 <h2>This is second bar. Class name "bar" again.</h2>
 <div class="selected-item">Selected İtem: <b>130</b></div>
 <label>
  <input type="radio" name="exa" value="150" />
  130
 </label>
 <label>
  <input type="radio" name="exa" value="140" />
  140
 </label>
 <label>
  <input type="radio" name="exa" value="150" />
  150
 </label>
 <label>
  <input type="radio" name="exa" value="160" />
  160
 </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jquery's `closest` which will go UP in the DOM looking for the selector. Then use `FIND` to search back DOWN the DOM for the appropriate fields.

```js
$('.bar input[name="exa"]').on('change', function() {
 var selectedprice = $(this).closest(".bar").find('input[name=exa]:checked').val();
 $(this).closest(".bar").find( ".selected-item b" ).text( selectedprice );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bar">
 <h2>This is first bar. class name "bar"</h2>
 <div class="selected-item">Selected İtem: <b>130</b></div>
 <label>
  <input type="radio" name="exa" value="130" />
  130
 </label>
 <label>
  <input type="radio" name="exa" value="140" />
  140
 </label>
 <label>
  <input type="radio" name="exa" value="150" />
  150
 </label>
 <label>
  <input type="radio" name="exa" value="160" />
  160
 </label>
</div>

<div class="bar">
 <h2>This is second bar. Class name "bar" again.</h2>
 <div class="selected-item">Selected İtem: <b>130</b></div>
 <label>
  <input type="radio" name="exa" value="130" />
  130
 </label>
 <label>
  <input type="radio" name="exa" value="140" />
  140
 </label>
 <label>
  <input type="radio" name="exa" value="150" />
  150
 </label>
 <label>
  <input type="radio" name="exa" value="160" />
  160
 </label>
</div>
```